# How do I run JUnit5 tests from the command line using the Console Launcher?

Tags: java, junit, command-line-interface, junit5

I compiled the tests and I am trying to run them doing the following:

```
> java -jar lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-M4.jar --class-path ./bin --select-class com.mycompany.DbTest
```

This throws a massive exception that starts like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/JUnitException
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
...
```

But basically says it can't find the JUnitException class. If instead I let the console launcher look for the tests, it finds no tests:

```
> java -jar lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-M4.jar -p bin/
╷
├─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
└─ JUnit Vintage ✔

Test run finished after 20 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

I am at a loss to know how can I run JUnit5 tests from the command line, without IDEs.

**Update:**

Using Maven to run the tests (with the Surefire plugin) gives me the same errors. I even removed all the tests but one that merely imports junit5 dependencies, and I still get the error.

Comment: Why is `java -jar …` twice in your command?

Comment: Oops, sorry bad copying, corrected now. Thanks! (that was not the problem, btw)

Comment: On which OS are you running the tests on?

Comment: Any endorsed/system jars in your Java runtime setup?

Comment: MacOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: Not that I know of. What's the best way to see that? I started the project in IntelliJ, could it be messing up somehow?

Comment: See this answer regarding Apple extension libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842423/1431016

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147657/discussion-between-sormuras-and-giantsquid).

Answer (score 1):

Your inital command line contains a duplication. A single "java -jar ..." should allow the Java runtime to find the bundled `JUnitException` class.

Use [options](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher-options) `--class-path` and `--scan-class-path` together to get the automatic scan running.

Something like:

`java -ea -jar lib/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.0.0-M4.jar --class-path bin --scan-class-path`

If you want to use a selector, like `--select-class`, you still have to provide the custom classpath with `--class-path bin`. Otherwise, only the standalone jar is on the classpath, which does not contain your tests.

Or there are JARs in the Mac [Extension Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12842423/1431016) folder that interfer with the test execution. Please remove them.

Comment: The command duplication was not the problem. The command you suggest gives me the exact same problem, JUnitException is not found.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, having JUnit 4 on the classpath was the problem for me as well. Make sure to remove all traces of it, either from macOS extensions folder or from your gradle dependencies. I had to use

```
configurations.compile {
    exclude group: 'junit'
}
```

to force remove it from everywhere, including transitive dependencies.